Simulating location route with react-native-maps in expo app for ios (google maps)
I have an app built with expo which use react-native-maps , specifically I'm using the Google map provider and trying to build/run on ios (running with expo start run:ios). I want to be able to simulate a user's location changing but am having a hard time figuring out how.
When I open Debug > Simulate location in the xcodeproj, all of the options are disabled. I tried running the app from XCode but get a bunch of build errors (eg: No such module 'ExpoModulesCore' and a bunch of module map file not found for various google related packages.

I've also tried generating a gpx file and sharing with the simulator and restarting the app with no luck. I would use one of the pre-made location routes but I need the route to be in NYC. How can I get a route simulated for my google map?
